# How to go about this (double integral?) problem?

Tags: integration

This question concerns the derivation of equations for calculating (1) the flow into a conically-shaped wellbore and (2) the inner cylindrical radius that would provide flow into a cylindrically-shaped wellbore (first figure) that is the same quantity of flow of the conically-shaped wellbore (second figure) if the height ($z=L$) and external radius of the flowing domain remains unchanged.

Consider the figure below which schematically illustrates the radial flow toward the inner cylinder (wellbore).

[image]

Eqn(1) is used to describe this flow ($q$),
$$\tag{1} q=\frac{kA_r}{\mu}\frac{dp}{dr}$$

where $A_r$ = cross-sectional area at radius $r$. The variables $k$ and $\mu$ are material constants. In this situation, any point in the larger cylinder (the flowing domain) the cross-sectional area across which flow occurs will be the surface area of a cylinder, which is $2\pi rL$.  After separating variables, Eqn(1) can be integrated between the two radii, $r_1$ and $r_2$, where the pressures are $p_1$ and $p_2$, respectively, yielding Eqn(2) for the total flow:

$$\frac{q}{2\pi L} \int_{r_1}^{r_2} \frac{dr}{r} = \frac{k}{\mu} \int_{p_1}^{p_2}dp$$
$$\tag{2} q=\frac{2\pi kL(p_2-p_1)}{\mu \ln(r_2/r_1)}$$

Now getting to the first question, suppose the radius of the inner cylinder is a function of height $z$ as shown in the figure below.

[image]

If we assume a linear relationship between $r$ and $z$, e.g., $r(z)=r_1+mz$, can we perform a double integration procedure following the logic used to derive Eqn(2)? How?

My current thought is this is a "method of discs"-type of problem, but I'm not sure. Perhaps I take the derivative of $r(z)$, giving me:

$$\frac{dr}{dz}=m \ dz$$

and somehow work that into the derivation?

The second question involves the derivation of the inner cylindrical radius that would provide flow into a cylindrically-shaped wellbore (first figure) that is the same quantity of flow of the conically-shaped wellbore (second figure) if the height ($z=L$) and external radius of the flowing domain remains unchanged.  At this moment I have no idea how I would begin to tackle this problem.